# For a stochastic process $X_n$, is $E[X_{n+1}]\leq X_n$ a stronger statement than $E[X_{n+1}|X_n] \leq X_n$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I think that if $X_n$ is a supermartingale then it implies the unconditional version in the title, but not sure about the reverse, I suspect not.